# Check If Product Exists

Tags: magento

I have some php code which I use SKU for it:

```
$sku = $id
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); //Get Product by ID (ASIN)
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); //if in stock
$_prodcats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

What I would like to add to this code if $sku is wrong (Not found in database with $_product line) to be able to change it manually for example if the $sku is not existent change it to $sku = "909010";

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function get_product($sku){

$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); 
    if (!$product){
        $new_sku = '909010'; // If Real SKU doesn`t exsist, change to '909010'
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$new_sku);
    }
    return $product;        
}

var_dump(get_product('your-sku')); // Real Sku
```

Comment: If you need a faster way to check if SKU doesn't exist you can do the folowing: `if (!Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku))`. This is super useful if you are looping through a large array and only need to create new products, and ignore the products that already exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sku = $id
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); //Get Product by ID (ASIN)
if(!is_object($_product) || !$_product->getId()){
    //do your stuff here
}
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); //if in stock
$_prodcats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sku = $id
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); //Get Product by ID (ASIN)

$_product = !empty($product) ? $product : Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','YOUR-ERROR-SKU');

$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); //if in stock
$_prodcats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```